# WL 6.0. Intalling custom war. Setting Datasrouces JNDI

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Worklight 6.0

For installing custom war, during the detailed installation using the websphere admin console, in "Step 6: Map resource references to resources" it asks for the datasources jndi.

Is it possible to specify these jndi entries in the worklight.properties file?

In 5.0.6 in the worklight.properties there were two variables wl.db.jndi.name and wl.reports.jndi.name that in 6.0 do not exist.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, those two properties are not supported in the 6.0 worklight.properties.  When upgrading your project, I expect you would see something like the following in your worklight.properties prepended to the existing line:
"# [wl.db.jndi.name is no longer supported]: ".  Similar for wl.reports.db.jndi.name.

Here is a link to the supported wl.db.* and wl.reports.* configuration properties, which are only supported in a development environment: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/r_ibm_worklight_database_setup.html?resultof=%22%77%6c%2e%64%62%22%20

Comment: Ok, so is there anyway to specify those jndi for avoid Step 6?. I understand there must be one way because in the infocenter [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/t_configuring_websphere_application_server_manually.html), in step 6 where the steps to install the war using the admin console are detailed there is no metion for configuring the datasources. Thank you.

Comment: I think this is the page you are looking for: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fadmin%2Ft_configuring_websphere_application_server_for_derby_manually.html

Comment: Hi Yotam, that link is for configuring the datasources, the question is about application deployment. If the step six is mandatory during deployment or is it possible to configure the application for not to manually configure those parameters during deployment.