# Worklight console app, update

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

We're using Worklight 6.1.0.0 / WebSphere 8.0.0.2 (ND/aix).
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301816/wl-6-0-intalling-custom-war-setting-datasrouces-jndi) seemed pretty close to my question too, but for version 6.0.

I've successfully done uninstall/install to our worklight console war package. However, there is some extra work on re-deploying adapters and such. I was looking for a way to just update the console. Among the ant tasks there is a target 'minimal-update', which sounds like what I'm looking for (is it?). However when all other pieces fell into place, I have an error for mapping the datasources:

ADMA0007E: A validation error occurred in task Mapping resource references to resources. The Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI) name is not specified for resource reference jdbc/WorklightDS in module Worklight with EJB name .

Contents of the 'minimal-update' task is pretty much the same as for 'install'.

I tried that as update from websphere admin console (but i should use the ant task - right?), that gave me a wizard screen to map jdbc/WorklightDS from package to jdbc/WorklightDS on server. This left me wondering how could I tell this using the ant task.

Answer (score 1):

The ant target minimal-update of the sample configuration files documented at http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/c_ant_tasks_sample_config_files.html is meant to update a WAR file already deployed (and not uninstalled). In particular, on WAS, it assumes that the JNDI datasources are in place.
If you have uninstalled the WAR file, you should use the target install instead, provided that your databases were created for Worklight 6.1. 
If they were created for a previous version of worklight you must upgrade their schema as well running the target 'databases' (and if it's a production installation, you might want to read all the steps in detail at http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrade_to_srvr610_in_production_env.html )